# Can I get <li>'s side by side without increasing size of the containing div?

Tags: html, css

**What I'm trying to do**

So, I have a `<div>`, in this `<div>` is a `<ul>` populated with `<li>`, each containing an `<img>`. I want these images to be lined up side by side so I can write some jquery to make them slide left and make it look like a teleprompter for images.

**Problem:**

I set the width of the `<div>` to 400px so that it fits one image as I want it to be centered in the middle of the website (I used margin: 0 auto; for this). I now cannot get the li elements to line up outside of the div to the right, they just appera below it (see image).

**So..**

Is there a way to get all my `<li>` elements sitting side by side left to right without increasing the size of the `<div>`? Or perhaps I can center it some other way and increase the width of the `<div>`... but then I wouldnt be able to use overflow:hidden to hide the `<li>` elements before they come on screen with jquery.

*HTML*

```
   <div id="slider">
        <ul class = "slides">
            <li class="slide" id="1"><img src="images/Coding.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2"><img src="images/Javascript.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="3"><img src="images/League_of_legends.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="4"><img src="images/Coding.png"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

*CSS*

```
#slider{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000;
    border-width:1px;
}
.slides{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.slide{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.slide img{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
```

*Image for example* (ignore the grey bar, thats just a placeholder for the footer)

[image: Broken li elements]

Edit: worth noting I tried floating the li's left but they still go beneath, presumably because they dont fit inside the containing div.

Comment: how you want to show the image slide horizontally or vertically? and how many image you want to show at one time?

Comment: You can't use existing library? e.g. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, may problems are already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position your ul absolute in the div. Then add display:inline-block to the images/lists. Add position:relative to your div and overflow:hidden

You may want to change the width of .slides a bit. You can use jquery to absolute position the ul differently and get it to slide

```
#slider{
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.slides{
    position:absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.slide,.slide img{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: changed width:...px to white-space: nowrap; as recommended by IMI

http://jsfiddle.net/nLb8ptmy/1/

Comment: You can remove the width declaration on `.slides` if you replace it with `white-space: nowrap;`. That way you do not have to change your CSS if you add more slides in the future. Also you may want to add `line-height:0;` to `.slides` to remove the space on the bottom of your slides.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)? You can then use `margin-left` on either the flexbox or its container (or `transform:translateX` even) to make it scroll).

```css
#slider > ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
        <ul class = "slides">
            <li class="slide" id="1"><img src="images/Coding.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="2"><img src="images/Javascript.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="3"><img src="images/League_of_legends.png"></li>
            <li class="slide" id="4"><img src="images/Coding.png"></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

[Some prefixing required depending on target browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent container to avoid wrapping. Set `overflow: hidden` to avoid the extra elements to be seen.

*Remove the overflow property to check how it is aligned.*

```css
#slider {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Avoiding other elements to be visible */
}
.slides {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Do not wrap to next line */
}
.slide {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.slide img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide" id="1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" id="2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" id="3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" id="4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use li {display: inline;} to get it side by side.

http://jsfiddle.net/18yao91v/262/

```
li{
     display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to display your `li` elements as blocks and float them left, so they will be listed horizontally.

```
#slider li{
  display:block;
  float: left
}
```

Ones this has been done, you need to hide the rest of the `li` elements other than the first element. (You can do this by adding a different class to first element).
Using jquery, you can switch that class between `li` elements and add some animation.